# JFreeChart on Linux without X - AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

When I execute this code in my VPS (virtual private server):

```
SortedSet<Integer> keys = new TreeSet<>(map.keySet());
DefaultCategoryDataset dateset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
for (Integer hour : keys) {
    dateset.addValue(map.get(hour), "", hour);
}
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart("Channel: ",
        "Hour", "Person", dateset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, false, false);
int width = 600; /* Width of the image */

int height = 480; /* Height of the image */

File lineChart = new File(channel_id + "_Chart.jpeg");
try {
    ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(lineChart, chart, width, height);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    App.sendLogger(ActivityCharts.class, "Error...
}
```

my xshell shows this error:

> Failed to execute Xmanager:

and:

> Exception in thread "pool-2-thread-2" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using 'localhost:10.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.

in line:

```
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart("Channel: ",
        "Hour", "Person", dateset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, false, false);
```

but when is start this program on my computer, all works.

Comment: ok i repair this but i have problem
when i addValue(map.get(hour),"",hour);
first value is integer but in charts i have values like this:
1,1/1,5/2,1
no integer but double;/ how to remove this?

Comment: please open an other question if you have one, as this way you will get answers much more likely.
you may also want to post the solution you found to this problem as an answer.